# jls. return-type-substitutable. What does it mean?

Tags: java, inheritance, methods, return, jls

I am reading jls and I faced with following term:

```
return-type-substitutable
```

snippet from jls

> A method declaration d1 with return type R1 is
>   return-type-substitutable for another method d2 with return type R2
>   iff any of the following is true:
>
> If R1 is void then R2 is void.
>
> If R1 is a primitive type then R2 is identical to R1.
>
> If R1 is a reference type then one of the following is true:
>
> --R1, adapted to the type parameters of d2 (§8.4.4), is a subtype of
>   R2.
>
> --R1 can be converted to a subtype of R2 by unchecked conversion
>   (§5.1.9).
>
> --d1 does not have the same signature as d2 (§8.4.2), and R1 = |R2|.

first two points is clearly.

can you clarify

> --R1, adapted to the type parameters of d2 (§8.4.4), is a subtype of R2.
>
> --R1 can be converted to a subtype of R2 by unchecked conversion (§5.1.9).
>
> --d1 does not have the same signature as d2 (§8.4.2), and R1 = |R2|.

thanks

P.S.
for Luiggi Mendoza

```
interface Foo {
        List<String> foo(String arg1, String arg2);
}

class Bar implements Foo {
    @Override
    public ArrayList<String> foo(String arg1, String arg2) {
        //implementation...
        return  null;
    }

    public String foo(String arg1, String arg2, String arg3) {
        //implementation...
        return  null;
    }
}
```

it is working variant.

### Cause of my question - I want to inderstand following phrase from jls:

> If a method declaration d1 with return type R1 overrides or hides the
>   declaration of another method d2 with return type R2, then d1 must be
>   return-type-substitutable (§8.4.5) for d2, or a compile-time error
>   occurs

### rule:

```
If R1 is a reference type then **one of the following** is true:
...
--d1 does not have the same signature as d2 (§8.4.2), and R1 = |R2|.
...
```

code:

```
interface Foo {
        List<String> foo(String arg1, String arg2);
}

class Bar implements Foo {
    @Override
    public List<String> anotherName(String arg1, String arg2,Object obj) {
           return  null;
    }
```

it is compile error.

R1==R2 (  `List<String > == List<String>`)

d1!=d2

Where have I broken the rule?

Comment: From your last edit, there's no `anotherName` method to override, thus you get a compiler error. Also, you say that `Bar` implements `Foo` but there's no `public List<String> foo(String arg1, String arg2)` method in `Bar` class (or another method which signature `foo(String arg1, String arg2)` that returns a `List` or a subtype of `List`).

Comment: @Luiggi Mendoza I wrote the rule and wrote code example according the my sight of this rule. Can you specify the places of rules where I have broken it?

Comment: I already pointed them in my comment.

Comment: @Luiggi Mendoza your comment is common. I accepted with it. But it is your java understandable. Imagine that you novice in java and tryes to follow rules.  Please add to your question update with following format: quote from rule - violation in my code.

Comment: I say about 2 rules:1. **If a method declaration d1 with return type R1 overrides or hides the declaration of another method d2 with return type R2, then d1 must be return-type-substitutable (§8.4.5) for d2, or a compile-time error occurs**   as d2 (§8.4.2), and R1 = |R2|

Comment: and 2.  **A method declaration d1 with return type R1 is return-type-substitutable for another method d2 with return type R2 iff any of the following is true: If R1 is a reference type then one of the following is true: d1 does not have the same signature as d2 (§8.4.2), and R1 = |R2|.**

Comment: The problem is not about being a novice or not, the problem is not grasping the concepts at all.

Comment: Posted another answer trying to explain the problem.

Comment: @Luiggi Mendoza I As I understood **If a method declaration d1 with return type R1 overrides or hides** implies that rules of hiding or overriding are observed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's have this interface

```
interface Foo {
    List<String> foo(String arg1, String arg2);
}
```

And a class implementing it

```
class Bar implements Foo {
    @Override
    public List<String> foo(String arg1, String arg2) {
        //implementation...
    }
}
```

We have:

- `Bar#foo` as `d1`
- `List<String>` return type in d1 as R1.
- `Foo#foo` as `d2`
- `List<String>` return type in d2 as R2.

> R1, adapted to the type parameters of d2 ([§8.4.4](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.4)), is a subtype of R2.

It means that `R1` can be a subtype of `R2`, which means R1 should pass the IS-A test. So, we can do the following:

```
class Bar implements Foo {
    @Override
    public ArrayList<String> foo(String arg1, String arg2) {
        //implementation...
    }
}
```

> R1 can be converted to a subtype of R2 by unchecked conversion ([§5.1.9](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.9)).

This is more related to generics. It means that `R1` should pass the IS-A test even if it throws a warning for unchecked overriding. So, we can do the following:

```
class Bar implements Foo {
    @Override
    public ArrayList foo(String arg1, String arg2) {
        //implementation...
    }
}
```

> d1 does not have the same signature as d2 ([§8.4.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.2)), and R1 = |R2|

This means overloading:

```
class Bar implements Foo {
    @Override
    public ArrayList<String> foo(String arg1, String arg2) {
        //implementation...
    }

    public ArrayList<String> foo(String arg1, String arg2, String arg3) {
        //implementation...
    }
}
```

Comment: **d1 does not have the same signature as d2** it is not enough exact for jls - I can write absolutely any signature.  and what does it mean  **  R1 = |R2| **

Comment: @gstackoverflow this means that you can return the same type for different signatures, which is another way to say overloading.

Comment: overloading - it is  situation when method name is same but different parameter list. It is not relates with return type

Comment: what about braces around tge R2 ?

Comment: @gstackoverflow it refers to class type.

Comment: **If R1 is a primitive type then R2 is identical to R1.** it is analog of this phrase for reference types?

Comment: @gstackoverflow yes, but you end learning lot of concepts and understanding how Java works.

Comment: In my brain I use another terms for explanation "How does java work"

Comment: please read update - I have misunderstanding of last point. I use differerent return types(R1 != |R2|) and it is not error anyway. details in topic update

Comment: @gstackoverflow that's the expected behavior. I don't understand what's the problem there. If d1 and d2 are completely different, and R1 and R2 are completely different as well, it should compile and run.

Comment: obviously I don't understand meaning of **d1 does not have the same signature as d2 (§8.4.2), and R1 = |R2|**

Comment: @gstackoverflow and my question is what you still don't understand.

Comment: looks like I  don't understand condition of using return-type-substitutable

Comment: @ Luiggi Mendoza from jls: **If a method declaration d1 with return type R1 overrides or hides the declaration of another method d2 with return type R2, then d1 must be return-type-substitutable (§8.4.5) for d2, or a compile-time error occurs**

Comment: @gstackoverflow well, you first have to understand the current rule in your original question. After that, try designing a case to break the other rule. For example, having a method with same signature and different return type.

Comment: I made it. please verify

Answer (score 0):

> If a method declaration d1 with return type R1 overrides or hides the declaration of another method d2 with return type R2, then d1 must be return-type-substitutable (§8.4.5) for d2, or a compile-time error occurs as d2 (§8.4.2), and R1 = |R2|.

Let's break this in pieces:

First, we need a method declaration `d2` and a return type `R2`:

```
class SomeClass {
    public List<String> d2() {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Now, we define a class extending `SomeClass` that defines `d1` and returns `R1`.

```
class AnotherClass extends SomeClass {
    //@Override annotation means it is overriding a method in parent class
    //d2 here is d1
    //Object here is R1
    @Override
    public List<String> d2() {
    }
}
```

How can this compile? Because `d1` is return-type-substitutable for `d2`, which means `R1` can replace `R2` as return type. This is also called [covariant return type](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariant_return_type) and is covered in [Java Tutorials. Returning a Value from a Method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/returnvalue.html). This is supported by the other rule:

> A method declaration d1 with return type R1 is return-type-substitutable for another method d2 with return type R2 if any of the following is true: If R1 is a reference type then one of the following is true: d1 does not have the same signature as d2 (§8.4.2), and R1 = |R2|.

Which means all of these methods are valid for overriding `SomeClass#d2`:

```
class AnotherClass extends SomeClass {
    //ArrayList implements List
    @Override
    public ArrayList<String> d2() {
        return null;
    }
}

class AnotherClass extends SomeClass {
    //raw List can be casted to `List<String>` by unchecked conversion
    //means you don't need a explicit cast to convert `List` to `List<String>`
    //due to type erasure
    @Override
    public List d2() {
        return null;
    }
}

class AnotherClass extends SomeClass {
    //combination of both examples above
    @Override
    public ArrayList d2() {
        return null;
    }
}
```

But these are invalid implementations:

```
class AnotherClass extends SomeClass {
    //the signature is not the same
    @Override
    public List<String> d1() {
        return null;
    }
}

class AnotherClass extends SomeClass {
    //Set is not a subtype of List
    @Override
    public Set<String> d2() {
        return null;
    }
}

class AnotherClass extends SomeClass {
    //Collection is not a subtype of List
    @Override
    public Collection<String> d2() {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: problem with following phrase: **d1 does not have the same signature as d2**

Comment: @gstackoverflow do you know what a signature is?

Comment: it is method name and argument list

Comment: @gstackoverflow ok, then in the last pieces of code, `d1` and `d2` **do not have the same signature, thus compiler error**. What part of that don't you understand?

Comment: According these rules  ** if d1 does not have the same signature as d2 (§8.4.2), and R1 = |R2|** then **method declaration d1 with return type R1 is return-type-substitutable for another method d2** then ...

Comment: **If a method declaration d1 with return type R1 overrides or hides the declaration of another method d2 with return type R2, then d1 must be return-type-substitutable (§8.4.5) for d2, or a compile-time error occurs**

Comment: @gstackoverflow but that **doesn't apply for method overriding**. Do you understand what means overriding? For overriding you need both methods to have **the same signature**. Since the moment `d1` and `d2` do not have the same signature, **it is not overriding at all**. Period.

Comment: @gstackoverflow by the way, the links in my answers aren't for decoration purpose. They complement the answer. I recommend you to read them.

Comment: aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa....  **d1 does not have the same signature as d2 (§8.4.2), and R1 = |R2|** I cannot violate overriding and hiding rules here ????

Comment: @gstackoverflow if d1 and d2 don't have the same signature, we cannot talk about overriding nor hiding. Are you aware of that?

Comment: I know about it but I tried blindly follow the rules

Comment: Is this rule **d1 does not have the same signature as d2** for hiding only at this case...

Comment: As I understand you emphasis on overriding in **If a method declaration d1 with return type R1 overrides or hides the declaration of another method d2 with return type R2, then d1 must be return-type-substitutable (§8.4.5) for d2, or a compile-time error occurs as d2 (§8.4.2), and R1 = |R2|.**.